# Intercept entity saving with ADO.NET Entities Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I want to invoke a validation function inside the entities objects right before they are stored with ObjectContext#SaveChanges().  Now, I can keep track of all changed objects myself and then loop through all of them and invoke their validation methods, but I suppose an easier approach would be implement some callback that ObjectContext will invoke before saving each entity.  Can the latter be done at all?  Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've figured out how.  Basically, we can intercept SavingChanges event of ObjectContext and loop through the newly added/modified entities to invoke their validation function.  Here's the code I used.

```
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        SavingChanges += PerformValidation;
    }

    void PerformValidation(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var objStateEntries = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
            EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified);

        var violatedRules = new List<RuleViolation>();
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objStateEntries)
        {
            var entity = entry.Entity as IRuleValidator;
            if (entity != null)
                violatedRules.AddRange(entity.Validate());
        }
        if (violatedRules.Count > 0)
            throw new ValidationException(violatedRules);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it that way, but it means that you're allowing your clients to directly access the ObjectContext, and, personally, I like to abstract that away, in order to make the clients more testable.

What I do is use the repository pattern, and do the validation when save is called on a repository.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good one.  But I tend to start simple first and only add more layers of abstraction only when necessary.  That said, the client tests does dig through EF and DB without any mock - not quite *unit* test but so far that works well.