# asp.net mvc equivalent of rails callback before_save

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, callback

Hi i'm looking for a asp.net mvc callback for elaborate data before save a model.

In rails there is before_save.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Entity Framework (which your tag indicates), then [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450601/intercept-entity-saving-with-ado-net-entities-framework) should be able to help you out.  Basically you can intercept the SavingChanges event, and do whatever you want.  Put this in a partial class that adds the following methods to your object context:

```
partial void OnContextCreated()
{
    SavingChanges += DoWhatYouMust;
}

private void DoWhatYouMust(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}
```