# Before save model in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When I wrote web applications in Rails, it was very easy to control events like before_action, before_save. How to use they in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: Could you add more detail on these events?  I'm not familiar with Rails, so I'm not sure what features in MVC 4 match with what you're looking for.

Comment: That has nothing to do with MVC. Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [in Entity framework, how to call a method on Entity before saving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677160/in-entity-framework-how-to-call-a-method-on-entity-before-saving)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Entity Framework

Comment: you could try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817456/asp-net-mvc-equivalent-of-rails-callback-before-save